# Problema ao executar o gulp

Tags: gulp

Meu Gulp funcionava normalmente, de uma hora para outra começou apresentar este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo `/var/www/html/dna/public/css/app.css` está com permissão 777.

Conteúdo do arquivo gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.styles(['normalize.css', 'flatcolors.css'], 'public/css/padrao.css')
        .styles(['bootstrap.min.css'], 'public/css/bootstrap.css');
    mix.scripts([   'jquery-2.1.4.js', 
            'bootstrap.min.js', 
            'functions.js', 
            'ajax.js', 
            'jquery.blockUI.js'
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontecia comigo direto. A solução que eu tive foi dando permissão para a pasta em que o `gulp` não estava tendo acesso:

```
 cd pasta_do_projeto
 sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Outra forma que eu utilizei para resolver o problema foi através do comando `chown`.

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
```

Você pode também substituir o `$(whoami)` por `$USER`.

Esse último comando tem como finalidade alterar o proprietário dos arquivos.

Comment: Com o `chown` funcionou, obrigada!

Comment: Esse +1 significa que deu certo?

Comment: Sim, deu certo :)